# Yodlee: Is there any way to get data for a Item with using itemAccountId?

Tags: json, yodlee, java

Currently I am integrating Yodlee and looking for getting data for a specific item by using itemAccountId. I am able to do site level refresh and getting data.

Thanks

Guys, May I know the reason for down vote so I can correct my mistakes on next time.
thanks

Comment: I guess you are looking for this https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getItemSummariesForSite. You can pass 'itemAccountId' as 'memSiteAccId' in api call

Comment: Thanks bunty, I believe and tried we can't use itemAccountId as memSiteAccId for getItemSummariesForSite call. If we use then we will get com.yodlee.core.InvalidSiteAccountException exception from yodlee service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to give you data using itemAccountID(i.e. per account) but there is an API which takes itemID(per container) and returns the accounts associated.
Try getItemSummaryForItem1 API.